# Angular conditional multi selection box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multipleselection

**Introduction**

I am trying to develop 2 selection (drop-down) boxes that populates the second box depending on the first selection.

*for example*

Choose product 1 and the second box will then have format 1, 2 and 5. 
choose product 2 and the second may have format 2, 3 and 6.

**Problem and Question**

The first box has been populated by my array, but the second box is not populating depending on the selection not the first, in fact its not populating at all (see screen shot.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">

    <div ng-controller="dropDown">
        <select ng-model="formData.ProductAndFormat" ng-options="product.name for product in productsandformats">
        </select>

        <select ng-model="formData.format" ng-if="user.productName"
                ng-options="format.id as format.name for Format in user.productName.format">
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
 .controller('dropDown', function ($scope) {

    $scope.productsandformats = [{
        "name": "product 1",
        "format": [{
            "name": "format 1",
            "id": "1"
        }, {
            "name": "format 2",
            "id": "2"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "product 2",
        "format": [{
            "name": "format 3",
            "id": "3"
        },{
            "name": "format 2",
            "id": "2"
        },
            {
            "name": "format 4",
            "id": "4"
        }, {
            "name": "format 5",
            "id": "5"
        }]
    }];

    $scope.user = {productName: $scope.productsandformats[0], format: '1'};

    $scope.displayModalValue = function () {
        console.log($scope.user.productName);
    }

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use this code `ng-options="format.id as format.name for format in formData.ProductAndFormat.format"` instead of your this code `ng-options="format.id as format.name for format in user.productName.format">` on your second `select` box

---

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('dropDown', function ($scope) {

    $scope.productsandformats = [{
        "name": "product 1",
        "format": [{
            "name": "format 1",
            "id": "1"
        }, {
            "name": "format 2",
            "id": "2"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "product 2",
        "format": [{
            "name": "format 3",
            "id": "3"
        },{
            "name": "format 2",
            "id": "2"
        },
            {
            "name": "format 4",
            "id": "4"
        }, {
            "name": "format 5",
            "id": "5"
        }]
    }];
      $scope.formData={};
    $scope.formData.ProductAndFormat =  $scope.productsandformats[0];
    $scope.displayModalValue = function () {
        console.log($scope.user.productName);
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="dropDown">
<div class="form-group">

    <div ng-controller="dropDown">
        <select ng-model="formData.ProductAndFormat" ng-options="product.name for product in productsandformats">
        </select>
        <select ng-model="formData.format" 
                ng-options="format.id as format.name for format in formData.ProductAndFormat.format">
        </select>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have Set default value for the first select box :) +1

Comment: @RameshRajendran, Thanks buddy for edit and up vote :)