# Angular - Get values from cascade selects

Tags: angularjs, select

i have this problem: in a HTML page i have two selects, the second one depends by the first one

HTML

```
FIRST

<select class="trip dark" ng-model="formSearch.selectedRegione" ng-options="regione.nome for regione in regioni.regionSelector">
                                            <option value="">TUTTE</option>
                                        </select>

SECOND

<select class="trip dark" ng-model="formSearch.selectProvincia" ng-options="provincia.nome for provincia in formSearch.selectedRegione.province">
                                            <option value="">TUTTE</option>
                                        </select>
```

The problem is when i get selected values from my controller, it returns object for the first one and 'undefined' for the second, and not the values ad i expect.

EDIT

All two selects work fine, it means that when i select a value in the first select, the second one is populated with right vales.

My problem is when in my controller i do this

```
var selectedRegione= $scope.formSearch.selectedRegione;
var selectedProvincia= $scope.formSearch.selectedProvincia;
```

selectedRegione returns object, selectedProvincia returns undefined

EDIT

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">

<div class="holder">
    <select class="trip dark" ng-model="formSearch.selectedRegione" ng-
      options="regione.nome for regione in regioni.regionSelector">
      <option value="">TUTTE</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="holder">
    <select class="trip dark" ng-model="formSearch.selectProvincia" ng-
      options="provincia.nome for provincia in formSearch.selectedRegione.province">
    <option value="">TUTTE</option>
    </select>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-trip" ng-click="ricercaAttivita()">Ricerca</button>

<div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
var tantoSvagoApp = angular.module('tantoSvagoApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui-rangeSlider']);

tantoSvagoApp.controller("mainController", function ($scope, serviceRegioni, 
                        srvShareData, $location, $window) {

$scope.ricercaAttivita = function() {
    var selectedRegione= $scope.formSearch.selectedRegione;
    var selectedProvincia= $scope.formSearch.selectedProvincia;

    console.log("selectedRegione  " + selectedRegione );
    console.log("selectedProvincia  " + selectedProvincia );
}
});
```

selectedRegione in object, selectedProvincia in undefined

Comment: I have made some changes just now for this answer, I hope it will helps you. Anyway it's  Possible duplicate of [Angular conditional multi selection box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266101/angular-conditional-multi-selection-box)

Comment: it seems the same thing that i do, in fact select works fine, the problem is when i get values

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: ok i paste HTML and Controller

Comment: Your ng-model is formSearch.selectProvincia. You're printing formSearch.selectedProvincia. Closing for typo. Note for future questions: what you post is not a complete example. It has many unknowns. This is what a complete minimal example looks like: http://plnkr.co/edit/2tvC9XXH5EEqKI5wsiMR?p=preview